# Can I use openid connect authentication and jwtbearer authentication scheme in one app?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core web app where the front-end is built in react and for the back-end, I have web APIs, both the things are placed in one web project.
for authentication, I used Azure AD open Id connect authentication scheme.

Now I have a requirement where I need to expose some APIs to an external system using client credentials flow. so I am not sure how to implement this in the current web app as it already has the open id connect authentication scheme.

Any idea?
Many thanks

Comment: see:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi

Comment: Was this sample helpful to you?

Comment: At some extent, there they have used "services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)" scheme explicitly in the startup.cs, but in my case, the web app's startup.cs has "services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)" scheme already, so can I add another authentication scheme?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work.

Comment: You cannot use oidc and client credential flow at the same time.

Comment: Okay but how to achieve this any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two applications in Azure portal. At present, you already have an ASP.NET Core Web application, which represents the **front-end** application, so you need to create another application that represents the Web API, that is, the **back-end** application.

First, you need to expose the api of the back-end application protected by Azure, which can be configured according to the following process:

**Azure portal>App registrations>Expose an API>Add a scope>Add a client application**

[image]

Then you need to create the **appRole** of the back-end application, and then grant that role as an **application permission** to the client application.

[image]

Next, go to **client application**>API permissions>Add a permission>**My APIs**>your api application.

[image]

Finally, you need to obtain an access token using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) where no user is logged in:

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Finally, you can pass the token to the api application, and the api application will authenticate the client application by parsing the token.

[Similar samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same case and solved it this way:

Startup.cs

```
string[] scopes = new[]
            {
                "openid",
                "profile",
                "offline_access",
                "email",
                "scope_one",
                "scope_two",
            };

                services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://my-own-indentity.com";
                    options.Audience = "Any_Audience";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                })  .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Authority = "https://Authority.com";
                    options.ClientId = "*****";
                    options.ClientSecret = "******";
                    options.CallbackPath = "/callback";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.ResponseType = OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.Code;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    foreach (string scope in scopes)
                    {

                        options.Scope.Add(scope);
                    }
                });
```

To be authenticated by "AddJwtBearer" for controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectController : ControllerBase
{ 
   //your code
}
```

To be authenticated by "AddOpenIdConnect" for controller::

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "oidc")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomethingWithOpenIdController : Controller
{
 //your code
}
```

If you found another solution feel free to share, otherwise I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs

```
// Add services to the container.
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, (options) =>
 {
     options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
     options.MetadataAddress = "metadataaddress";
     options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = "portal.com";
     // or any specific option used for your application
 });
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
            options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                // or any specific option used for your application
            });
```

In Controllers:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
```

This worked for me :)